# .netcore 2.2 Httpcontext doesn't have SignInAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to add Authentication to my application.
There is my code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace OlegTarOpenId
{
    public class OpenIdMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public OpenIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim("name", "Oleg")
            };
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Google");
            // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
            await context.SignInAsync("Google", new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));//<-- There is the error
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

I added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions to my project. But I don't know why context doesn't see the extension method SignInAsync.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity's SignInManager has a [SignInAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: @Oleg, I have copied your code into my project and I see everything is fine. `HttpConext` see the extension method `SignInAsync`. May be any external agent is playing a role here.

Comment: I don't see the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` namespace.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Did you create .netstandard library project?

Comment: @Sasan I can find Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication in Nugets

Comment: @Oleg Try this on your class library : `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity -Version 2.2.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SignInAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1) is an extension method that lives in [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions/) and lives inside the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` namespace.

In your case, it looks like you just need to add the `using` statement:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
```

This is separate from ASP.NET Core Identity and the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` packages.